# forgot password in cuba

Tags: cuba-platform, cuba

On most websites, there is an option to get the system to reset the user’s password if they forgot

the password. A new random password is sent to the user’s email after answering some secret

question. The “Forgot Password” option is available on the login screen.

Does Cuba platform have this option ? I could not find it in the documentation or any sample app.

How can I develop this function and change the login screen ?

Comment: This can be helpful to u: https://github.com/cubait/cuba-component-forgot-password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in CUBA for this case. You can extend the login window and implement the "forgotten password" case by yourself. The example of extending login screen is here: https://github.com/cuba-labs/brand-login

Comment: There is a "forgot password" add-on: https://www.jmix.io/cuba-platform/marketplace/forgot-password/
It doesn't support 7.2 version but can be easily migrated if necessary.